# how to make css work with php?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to take a .php log in script and make it look like the rest of my HTML web page.

I was told I could do this by using .css and this script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

thing is what do I do with that script? I need to take the html file and make it work with my .php so that my log in page matches the rest of my web site instead of just being a white page with username and password boxes. thanks.

---

```
<?php include('_header.php'); ?> 
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform"> 
     <label for="user_name"><?php echo WORDING_USERNAME; ?></label> 
     <input id="user_name" type="text" name="user_name" required /> 
     <label for="user_password"><?php echo WORDING_PASSWORD; ?></label> 
     <input id="user_password" type="password" name="user_password" autocomplete="off" required /> 
     <input type="checkbox" id="user_rememberme" name="user_rememberme" value="1" />    
     <label for="user_rememberme">

 <?php echo WORDING_REMEMBER_ME;
```

Comment: Did you know you can mix HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP together in one page? You can use that to combine PHP and CSS.

Comment: Grap a book and learn to code!

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question doesn't really make sense. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: that seem like it would be more complicated then just adding a .css file to make the .php file look the same. I'm using a premade website template.

Comment: the problem is I have a log in script that's in .php with a MySql database. my website is in HTML but I want users to have to log in to my web site before having access to any thing on it. I made the log in script in .php but I cant just add it to the HTML page script. right now when you go to my site my main page is a white screen with a user name and password box. I want my log in screen to look the same as the rest of my web site.

Comment: You need to make sure the file `style.css` exists in the same folder where your php script is.

Comment: Styling the html output of the page that will include this script, might be proved the easy thing. But reading your question and many of the comments here, I do not see how you make it work as a login script checking records from a database of users.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Web-page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo "Page title created with PHP"; ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

You can style this page using style.css in any way you wish. And at the same time: Use PHP for the login handling

Comment: I have a premade web site I downloaded. There's no way I can just take the HTML code and convert it to .css?

Comment: May i suggest you learn more about the concept of websites and its programming before asking this kind of question? It is a very broad question to ask here on Stackoverflow. I can suggest this to get you started: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC1322B5A0180C946 And 
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWFD41D_LDomY1Fb-O9MtFqq

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and explain why you cant do this.  In websites there are two types of programs ones run on the [server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) before the data is sent to the browser.  The other type is sent to your [browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) and run there.

**PHP** is server sided.  All the code in a PHP script is run on the server processed formatted what ever. Then the information is sent across the internet to your browser for display.

**CSS** and **Javascript** are also sent to your browser but its the code that's sent. The browser runs the code.  The server has nothing to do with them.

It might be a god idea that you find some basic PHP, HTML tutorials to start with.

Comment: Thanks that did help a bit. I'm reading through watching some tutorials now. I'm just trying to figure out how to make my .php log in script look the same as the rest of my web page. I'm getting a bit closer to the answer. ;)

Comment: remember only the stuff in <?php ... ?> is acutaly php.    Just becouse the file says .php doesnt mean the hole file is PHP.  What you probably want to change is the HTML and CSS.

Comment: I already have a .css file that makes the image for my site, is there any way I can just copy this and add a line some where so I can use it with the .php log in script I created?

Comment: is there a <head></head> tag in that script?

Comment: <?php include('_header.php'); ?>

<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform">
 <label for="user_name"><?php echo WORDING_USERNAME; ?></label>
 <input id="user_name" type="text" name="user_name" required />
 <label for="user_password"><?php echo WORDING_PASSWORD; ?></label>
 <input id="user_password" type="password" name="user_password" autocomplete="off" required />
 <input type="checkbox" id="user_rememberme" name="user_rememberme" value="1" />
 <label for="user_rememberme"><?php echo WORDING_REMEMBER_ME;

Comment: thats the beggining half

Comment: open _header.php its probably in there.

Comment: yes it was in the _header.php now I copy that link in there some where?